# How do I backup symbolic links?

Tags: linux, debian, symbolic-link

I created a ton of symbolic links using `ln -s ../folder/subfolder mylinkname`.

How can I back this folder of "links" up so I could restore it at a later date?  A compressed file or something similar would be ideal so I could move it off onto another Linux box while I rebuild it.

Comment: Just `tar` them?

Comment: I knew it was a stupid question being a complete novice with Linux. I was trying to use gzip and getting errors - figured it would require some clever workaround or something. Fail.

Comment: Gzip and Bzip2 can only handle a single file as input. They *compress*, they don't *achive*. That's why they're usually combined with `tar`.

Comment: Just a warning, because it's not quite clear what you want: the `tar` solution will only backup the symlinks themselves, _not_ the content they link to.

Comment: That's what I'm after - just backing the folder of links up, no content. Thanks for the heads up though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ad Daniel commented, you can backup the directory using tar.

```
tar -cvf folder.tar folder
```

You can add compression using -j or -z if you want to, check `man tar` or `info tar`